# Prove that $z_0$ is a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $z_0$ be an isolated singularity of a holomorphic function $f$. Suppose that there are $A, \epsilon > 0$ such that for all $z$ sufficiently close to $z_0$ we have
$$|f(z)| \leq \frac{A}{|z - z_0|^{1 - \epsilon}}\ .$$
Prove that $z_0$ is a removable singularity.

Can someone please show me how to do this problem? Thank you.

Comment: A good start is to state the exact definition of a removable singularity. The answer will follow.

Comment: Should be $A,\epsilon>0$, yes?

Comment: I imagine that you mean $A, \epsilon> 0$?

Comment: yeah, you are right. $\epsilon$ should be greater than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

Either you know Riemann's theorem on removable singularity and the result is just a conclusion of that theorem.

If not, define $$h(z) = \begin{cases} (z-z_0)^2f(z) &\mbox{if } z \neq z_0 \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } z=z_0 \end{cases}$$ and prove that $h$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=z_0$. Then consider the Taylor series of $h$ about $z_0$. Notice that $h(z_0)=h^\prime(z_0)=0$.

Comment: The way I used to do this problem is compute the residue of $f(z)$

Comment: Computing the residue is another good way.